# Building a Simple RSS reader, retrieving content

Tags: c#, rss, syndication-feed

I am trying to make a simple RSS reader using [`SyndicationFeed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class.

There are some standard tags, like `<title>`, `<link>`, `<description>`... there is no problem with them.

But there are some other tags. for example, in [this feed](http://feed.2barnamenevis.com/2barnamenevis), which created by WordPress, there is `<content:encoded>` tag. I think there may be other tags for the content part of other websites. right?

I want to know, how to find the main content of every post, is there any standards? which tags should I look for?

(for example, a site may use `<content:encoded>` but some other just use `<description>` or someone use another standard... I don't know what to do for retrieving the **main** content of a post)

P.S : I'm using this code for testing my simple RSS reader:

```
        var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://feed.2barnamenevis.com/2barnamenevis");
        var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        string s = "";
        foreach (SyndicationItem i in feed.Items)
        {
            s += i.Title.Text + "<br />" + i.Summary.Text + "<br />" + i.PublishDate.ToString() + "<br />";
            foreach (SyndicationElementExtension extension in i.ElementExtensions)
            {
                XElement ele = extension.GetObject<XElement>();
                s += ele.Name + " :: " + ele.Value + "<br />";
            }
            s += "<hr />";
        }
        return s;
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to support. Content element isn't part of RSS2.0 but is is of Atom (rss 4287).
Read RSS2.0 specs http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt

Comment: Last time I tried writing a RSS reader, I eventually gave up after I realized that a significant number of feeds out there don't follow any standards. The major readers out there must be very forgiving when it comes to reading feeds. I see it kind of like browsers reading webpages - if people follow the standards, there's no problem, but if not, you'll be writing custom stuff all day long to handle the one-off scenarios.

Comment: @JoeEnos What does other feed reader applications do? They can read every feed. How they do that?!

Comment: I don't know for sure, but if I had to guess, I'd say months and years of trial-and-error, testing every feed they can get their hands on, analyzing the failures, and writing custom parsing to handle them. For example, if the date standard is `Tue, 15 Mar 2012 08:45:46 -0700`, your parser would expect that. Until some joker puts `2012-03-15 08:45:46 -7` in that XML field, and your parser breaks. So you allow your parser to accept both, which is fine until some other joker names the author tag `<Author>` instead of `<author>` - etc.

Comment: Seems that building an RSS reader is a BIG project! Isn't there any third party RSS Reader framework for .Net that supports all of these??

Comment: I haven't used them, but [Argotic](http://argotic.codeplex.com/) and [RSS.NET](http://www.rssdotnet.com/) look like they might be good.

Comment: @JoeEnos Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [Argotic](http://argotic.codeplex.com/) Syndication Framework (thanks from JoeEnos).

Argotic has many Extensions, which can be used for handling elements which are not standard.

For example, You can use `Argotic.Extensions.Core.SiteSummaryContentSyndicationExtension` for retrieving `<content:encoded>`. You can see an example [here](http://frederictorres.blogspot.com/2011/01/reading-rss-feed-with-argotic.html). (if that example returns `null` for content, you should simply use `MyRssItem.Description`)

Some other useful extensions are `WellFormedWebCommentsSyndicationExtension` (for retrieving comments feed url) and `SiteSummarySlashSyndicationExtension` (for retrieving comments count).

Answer (score 3):

From our discussion in the comments, I'd probably suggest going with a 3rd party vendor instead of building it from scratch - [Argotic](http://argotic.codeplex.com/) and [RSS.NET](http://www.rssdotnet.com/) both look promising.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to support. Content element isn't part of RSS2.0 but is is of Atom (rss 4287).

Read RSS2.0 specs http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt
Read Atom specs https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287

Comment: I just want to support popular formats, like every feed reader application that is available... Feed reader applications can read everything, with any type of content tag...